# Can I await on IProgress.Report

Tags: c#, async-await, task-parallel-library

I'm following the pattern described at: https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/dotnet/2012/06/06/async-in-4-5-enabling-progress-and-cancellation-in-async-apis/ so I'm using IProgress.Report in my async method to report back the progress.

```
public async Task MyFirstTaskAsync(IProgress<T> progress)
{
    progress.report(some T)
}

public async Task MySecondTaskAsync(IProgress<T> progress)
{
    progress.report(some T)
}
```

On the UI thread, I'll call MyFirstTaskAsync and MySecondTaskAsync sequentially.

```
var reportProgress1 = new Action<T> (x =>Console.WriteLine("First Step Completed"))
var reportProgress2 = new Action<T> (x =>Console.WriteLine("Last Step Completed"))
var progress1 = new Progress<T>(reportProgress1 )
var progress2 = new Progress<T>(reportProgress2 )
await MyFirstTaskAsync(progress1)
Console.WriteLine("Second Step Comppleted")
await MySecondTaskAsync(progress2)
//code in reportProgress1.report can actually be executed at this point...
```

My problem here is code in reportProgress1.report can actually get executed after MyFirstTaskAsync has completed, which kinda messes up the progress report because I was expecting the first await can await until the progress report inside the first async method is also completed.

Is this a behavior I can somehow tweak to fit my need?

Thanks.

Edit: Suppose there're some non-async code between two tasks, and these three together are completing the overall process and each of them will update the progress as they run so they'll have to update the UI in a sequential order..

Comment: Thanks. I updated the question to clarify my problem. It's basically the tasks are together completing an overall process so I'll want their progress updates to happen in a specific order.

Answer (score 4):

No, you can't "await" `IProgress.Report`. Progress reports are essentially fire-and-forget.

You can, however, use your own implementation of `IProgress` with appropriate semantics. In particular, Reactive Extensions is good for taming "streams of data" (in this case, streams of progress reports).

Comment: Ah..thanks..I can see `Progress.Report` uses `SynchronizationContext.Post`to execute the code and like you said I guess this is just 'fire-and-forget'.. is there an easy way to execute something immediately on a synchronizationContext

Comment: @Godsent: Yes, `Send` is synchronous.

Comment: Thanks, that works. I just copied/pasted all existing `Progress` code to `ProgressWithSyncReport` class and changed `SynchronizationContext.Send` to `SynchronizationContext.Post` .. I also find it puzzling despite that `OnReport` method in `Progress` class is virtual, but I can't just override it to inherit because everything else is private...